# Controlling checkmark on menu item with Key value binding to first responder?

Tags: macos, menu, key-value-observing

I need to add a menu item that toggles a flag in the front document. I know how to do that `validateUserInterfaceItem`, but I'd really like to use Key Value Binding, so the menu item's checked/unchecked state switch based on the state of a flag in the front document (and the menu item is disabled if the first responder doesn't have the appropriate property.)

Is that possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible: in the nib editor’s Bindings inspector, bind the menu item’s **Value** to the appropriate property (**Model Key Path**) of the appropriate object (e.g., “File’s Owner”).

To have it disabled when it isn't applicable, ensure that “Conditionally Sets Enabled” is selected in the binding options.